# Getting an error that says: found value, required variable in Java

Tags: java, variables, types, blackjack

I am trying to create a computer generated Black Jack that shuffles 54 cards and displays them along with the score and if the person gets blackjack or not. I keep on getting this error and I have no idea why, if anyone can help, that would be great (:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DisplayCards extends JFrame {
public DisplayCards() {
    int cardCount = 54;
    Random ran = new Random();
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4,5,5));

    //Generate 3 random numbers
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
      int imageId = ran.nextInt(cardCount)+1;
      int blackjack = 0,
            result = 0;
      add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image/card/"+imageId+".png")));

        switch (imageId)
        {
        case 1:
                blackjack = 1;

        case 2:
                blackjack = 2;

            case 3:
                blackjack = 3;

            case 4:
                blackjack = 4;

            case 5:
                blackjack = 5;

            case 6:
                blackjack = 6;

            case 7:
                blackjack = 7;

            case 8:
                blackjack = 8;

            case 9:
                blackjack = 9;

            case 10:
                blackjack = 10;

            case 11:
                blackjack = 10;

        case 12:
                blackjack = 10;

            case 13:
                blackjack = 10;

            case 14:
                blackjack = 1;

            case 15:
                blackjack = 2;

            case 16:
                blackjack = 3;

            case 17:
                blackjack = 4;

            case 18:
                blackjack = 5;

            case 19:
                blackjack = 6;

            case 20:
                blackjack = 7;

            case 21:
                blackjack = 8;

        case 22:
                blackjack = 9;

            case 23:
                blackjack = 10;

            case 24:
                blackjack = 10;

            case 25:
                blackjack = 10;

            case 26:
                blackjack = 10;

            case 27:
                blackjack = 1;

            case 28:
                blackjack = 2;

            case 29:
                blackjack = 3;

            case 30:
                blackjack = 4;

            case 31:
                blackjack = 5;

        case 32:
                blackjack = 6;

            case 33:
                blackjack = 7;

            case 34:
                blackjack = 8;

            case 35:
                blackjack = 9;

            case 36:
                blackjack = 10;

            case 37:
                blackjack = 10;

            case 38:
                blackjack = 10;

            case 39:
                blackjack = 10;

            case 40:
                blackjack = 1;

            case 41:
                blackjack = 2;

        case 42:
                blackjack = 3;

            case 43:
                blackjack = 4;

            case 44:
                blackjack = 5;

            case 45:
                blackjack = 6;

            case 46:
                blackjack = 7;

            case 47:
                blackjack = 8;

            case 48:
                blackjack = 9;

            case 49:
                blackjack = 10;

            case 50:
                blackjack = 10;

            case 51:
                blackjack = 10;

        case 52:
                blackjack = 10;

            case 53:
                blackjack = 0;

            case 54:
                blackjack = 0;

            blackjack + result = result; // error here
    }
}
    //add(new JLabel(result));
    //if (result == 21)
    add(new JLabel("Black Jack!"));
    //else if(result != 21)
    //add(new JLabel("Sorry, You do not have Black Jack."));

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DisplayCards frame = new DisplayCards();
    frame.setTitle("Black Jack!");
    frame.setSize(300, 170);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Error:

```
DisplayCards.java:196: error: unexpected type
            blackjack + result = result; 
                      ^
 required: variable
 found:    value
 1 error
```

Comment: And what exactly are you expecting that line of code to do?

Comment: By the way, that `switch/case` statement really doesn't do what you think it does.  You should re-read that section of the tutorial, paying particular attention to the part that mentions the `break` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you should perform assignments like this:

```
result = blackjack + result;
```

Probably it should also a good idea for you to follow a basic tutorial on the language. Try this [one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).